# Test contents of file in rspec from respond_to format.csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails, respond-to

I have the following code in my controller that exports a csv file

```
...
  def export
    @filename = 'users.csv'
    @output_encoding = 'UTF-8'
    @users = User.active_users #not the actual scope but this only returns active
    respond_to do |format|
      format.csv
    end
  end
...
```

And I have the following in my spec

```
it "should only return active users"
  get :export, :format => :csv
  # i want to check that my mocked users_controller#export is only returning the active users and not the inactive ones  
end
```

`response.body` is empty in this test when i check it. How would I go about getting the csv file in the spec that is downloaded when this action is hit in a browser so that i can check the result? I've hit a bit of a wall trying to figure this out.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

A test that checks that a CSV file is being created is as follows, assuming that the controller action is at 'csv_create_path'

```
it 'should create a CSV file ' do
    get csv_create_path
    response.header['Content-Type'].should include 'text/csv'
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You sort of specify that CSV format is supported, but not what the contents should be. You could do

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.csv do
    render text: File.read(@filename)
  end
end
```

to actually render that CSV file.

If you also have a normal HTML formatted view for the same data, you would simply have

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv do
    render text: File.read(@filename)
  end
end
```

assuming you have setup appropriate instance variables for the HTML view before.